# how can we reduce the size of a character array in Java?

Tags: java

There are ways in which we can reduce the array size using a new array. But I want to know how we can do it without using an additional array.

Comment: what do you mean, "reduce the size"? free up memory of no-longer needed parts of the array?

Comment: i need to delete duplicate elements from the array

Comment: Java doesn't particularly support the in-place deletion of entries from an array. Array sizes are static, last I checked.

Answer (score 3):

Once an array is created, you cannot change the size. You can either create a new Array, or use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (internally, however, the ArrayList creates a new array, but this is hidden from you).

Comment: He stated "using a new array"

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to reduce element size of array ?
if yes, i think the only way to do it using copy the original array to new array that have smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are static in size. When you initialize an array with a given size, it will always have that size. Think of an Array as an egg carton. It may or may not have eggs in each of its slots, but it will always have 12 slots (or 6 or 18 or however many).

As far as deleting duplicates, you can replace duplicates you encounter with null, which makes the slot "empty".

```
public static void deleteDuplicates(Character[] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(arr[j] != null && arr[j].equals(arr[i]){
                //Found duplicate - delete duplicate and stop searching
                arr[i] = null;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```